# PHP SELECT distinct doesn't echo variable?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, distinct

```
$query = "SELECT distinct('case'), firstname, lastname 
            FROM cases ";
```

Why can't "case" be echoed? It is a number..

It will echo when the query is like this:

```
$query = "SELECT case, firstname, lastname 
            FROM cases ";
```

Comment: It might help  if you show the code you're using to 'echo' the variable.

Comment: Your second query is invalid - `case` is a reserved word in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: If you really want DISTINCT(`case`) use GROUP BY `case` that will return rows with the same case rather than all distinct rows

Answer (score 5):

First, case should not be in quotes, it should be in backticks. Second, DISTINCT always applies to the whole row regardless of any parentheses you may have around any of your expressions. In your query your parentheses are misleading and should be removed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `case`, firstname, lastname FROM cases
```

If you want to return a single aggregated row for each `case` you need to use "GROUP BY `case`", but then you need to consider what should be returned for the other values.

Answer (score 0):

The case is not echoed because you might be trying to echo `$row['case']` which wont work because the feild that is returning is not `case` but `distinct(case)`

And you need to avoid the single quote and either give no quotes or use a backquote; else mysql will take case as a literal string

so change the query to

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(case),
    firstname,
    lastname
FROM
    cases
```

And if you want to access the case as `$row['case']` the use `as` like

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(case) as case,
    firstname,
    lastname
FROM
    cases
```